# XTK : Create new custom fibers

Tags: javascript, xtk

Could you give us a short piece of code, showing us how to display a hand made fiber, for example a fiber from point a[0,0,0], passing by b[0,5,0], finishing on c[10,10,10], giving it a custom color, #47A3DA, and a custom lineWidth: 20?

I'm working on connectivity and graph theory and I'd like to display the different links computed between nodes and the API and examples don't help me enough to manipulate X.triplets and X.fibers.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a fiber object, then fill it in the same way it is done in the TRK parser:
https://github.com/xtk/X/blob/master/io/parserTRK.js

My 2cts